# Install iconv on Arch/manjaro

Tags: function, call, iconv, manjaro

I get this error on Symfony:

> Attempted to call function "iconv" from the global namespace.

I've got an answer from here to uncomment "extension=iconv" in the `/etc/php/php.ini` file. But `iconv` itself is not installed. I've already installed the `libiconv` and the `libticonv` package, but it still does not work.

I'm on Manjaro.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and after installing `php72` I just had to do what you said, composer worked just after uncommenting the line in `/etc/php72/php.ini`